# How do I change the text for taunts?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I know you can taunt when playing a game online by hitting a direction on the directional pad.

How do you customize what these taunts say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not under Online.  Instead, from the main menu:

- Choose "Games & More"
- Choose "Options"
- Choose "Internet Options"
- Choose "Profile"
- Press the direction on the directional pad that you want to change and the text entry screen will open.

The first 8 characters appear on the first line and the last 8 characters appear on the second line.  This screen is also where you set your online icon and phrase.

Comment: This is a good question and answer - you do not need to give justification for it within itself.  It should, and does, stand by its own merits.  Edited accordingly.